# Firefox Extension Set Proxy Auth

Tags: firefox, proxy, firefox-addon

I am trying to develop and Firefox Extension, which sets a proxy and does some other things after doing that. So i know how to set proxy http and port.

```
var prefManager = Cc["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIPrefBranch);
prefManager.setIntPref("network.proxy.type", 1);
prefManager.setCharPref("network.proxy.http",aProxy[0]);
prefManager.setIntPref("network.proxy.http_port",aProxy[1]);
```

But i was not able to find the properties for username and password. Seems it will need to be set differently.

Someone can help?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried saving the passwords using `nsILoginManager`? In Firefox, password for proxies are handled like any other password.

```
let LoginInfo = new Components.Constructor("@mozilla.org/login-manager/loginInfo;1", Components.interfaces.nsILoginInfo, "init");

let loginInfo = new LoginInfo(
    hostname,
    null,
    realm,
    user,
    password,
    '',
    ''
);

let loginManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/login-manager;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsILoginManager);
loginManager.addLogin(loginInfo);
```

Proxies don't have a scheme, so I've seen code in Firefox do something like this (code from https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/69d61e42d5df/toolkit/components/passwordmgr/nsLoginManagerPrompter.js#l1400):

```
// Proxies don't have a scheme, but we'll use "moz-proxy://"
// so that it's more obvious what the login is for.
var idnService = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/idn-service;1"].
                 getService(Ci.nsIIDNService);
hostname = "moz-proxy://" +
           idnService.convertUTF8toACE(info.host) +
           ":" + info.port;
realm = aAuthInfo.realm;
if (!realm)
  realm = hostname;
```

I think it's just for readability (when the user opens the password manager), but it shouldn't be required.

P.S.: There's also a preference, `signon.autologin.proxy`, that makes Firefox not prompt for authentication if a password is saved.